# Цифровая подпись Эль Гамаля

Tags: c#, хеширование, криптография

Смотрю в `Wikipedia` данный алгоритм. Вошел в ступор при генерации хеша для текста `M`

```
  string M = "baaqab";
  var y = BigInteger.ModPow(g, x, p);
  var hM = CalculateMD5Hash(M);
  var r = BigInteger.ModPow(g, k, p);
```

В `hM` у нас получается строка `8A79B2FA38507C93B87022C065DEA270`. Дальше при вычислении `s` мы отнимаем от `m-xr`. Понятно что в статье все переменные целочисленные и у них можно от числа 3 отнять другое число) Но у меня хеш. Там половина цифр, половина текст. Мне кажется я не ту функцию хеширования использую для строки M. Кто может подсказать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Но у меня хеш. Там половина цифр, половина текст* - В каком смысле? Хэш -  это некоторое число, получаемое из строки. Откуда у вас в нем текст?

Comment: Вообще в чистом виде (не у вас в языке, в общем случае) MD5 выдает   16 байт данных, которые можно рассматривать как большое число. Потом при выдаче его вам его записывают в привычном людям 16тиричном виде. Часто кроме выдающих 16-ричную запись бывают функции дающие сырое значние. Вам просто надо найти способ конвертировать это в ваш BigInt

Answer (score 1):

Ваша реализация `CalculateMD5Hash` зачем-то конвертирует численное значение MD5 в строку. Скорее всего у вас код вроде:

```
public string CalculateMD5Hash(string input)
{
    // step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input
    MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

    // step 2, convert byte array to hex string
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Уберите из него преобразование в строку, оставьте только само хэширование:

```
public BigInteger CalculateMD5Hash(string input)
{
    MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

    // добавить байт в конце чтобы получить гарантированно положительное значение
    return new BigInteger(hash.Concat(new byte[] { 0 }).ToArray());
}
```

и работайте с хэшем как с большим числом.

Comment: Вопрос а догонку) а зачем гарантировано получать положительные значения?

Comment: @Radzhab654654 последний байт (на самом деле первый, просто BigInteger использует обратную последовательность байт) - знаковый. Если не дописать 0, и если первый бит знакового байта будет 1 - то сам этот бит "потеряется", а число станет отрицательным (причем не тем, которое было в оригинале)